# making a text box same size as previous one

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following code on my form and I want to make the width of Address1 text box same as Last Name Text box. The width of Adress1` text box should end at where the width of Last Name text box is ending. Below is my code:

```html
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <label>First Name</label><br />
        <input runat="server" ID="fName" class="textboxsizeLarge borderText" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <label>Middle Name</label><br />
        <input runat="server" ID="MdName" class="textBoxSizMd borderText" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <label>Last Name</label><br />
        <input runat="server" ID="lname" class="textboxsizeLarge borderText" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-3">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <label>Address1</label><br />
        <input runat="server" ID="address1" class="borderText col-md-12" />
      </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-3">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <label>Address2</label><br />
        <input runat="server" ID="address2" class="borderText  col-md-12" />
      </div>
        </div>


<style>
.textboxsizeLarge{
 
    width:70%;
}

.textBoxSizMd {
    width: 30%;
}



.textboxsizebig {
    width: 100%;
}

.borderText {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 1px;
}
</style>
```

My screen shot of the text box looks like so:

[image]

I want the width of Address1 extended all the way till the end of last Name text box so that the address1 looks aligned with last Name text box.

Comment: Your code seems fine: https://jsfiddle.net/xmspnr1w/.

Comment: Last Name text box is smaller . I want both last Name and address1 text box to be aligned at the end.

Comment: If you look at the image above. I want the Address1 text box to be aligned properly with the lastName text box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like you're not using the `col-md` properly. You're specifying the width of the text box within a `col-md-4` which is already restricting the size so it's not remaining consistent across elements.

I drafted up a quick codepen to show you an example: https://codepen.io/sean-mooney/pen/rNOqaLb

I'm using the `col-md-4` and `col-md-12` to specify the textbox container's size and then having the textbox remain consistently at 100% width. This way the textbox will grow and shrink with the container which is specified by the column size you specify.

Hope that helps!